# Distinct from two fields in dictionary c#

Tags: c#, xml

Hi i have this code to fill my dictionary with data from xml file 
This is how it looks like(doc1 is xmldocument)

```
 dict = doc1.Elements()
                .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName != "Country") 
                .GroupBy(x => x.Name.LocalName, y => y == null ? "" : (string)y)
                .ToDictionary(x => x.Key,
                    y => y.Key == "OpenedDate" ?
                        DateTime.ParseExact(y.FirstOrDefault(), "yyyy-mm-dd", null).ToString("dd-mm-yyyy") :
                        y.FirstOrDefault());
```

I wanna ask, is it possible, in the where part , to add two fields: `Country`, and lets say another one `OldName`
I hope i am clear.
What i wanna achieve is to exclude two fields (`country and OldName`) from filling into `dict`

To be more clear , i wanna change this

```
.Where(x => x.Name.LocalName != "Country")
```

To something like

```
.Where(x => x.Name.LocalName != "Country", x => x.Name.LocalName != "OldName") 
Or 
.Where(x => x.Name.LocalName != "Country" && x.Name.LocalName != "OldName"
```

Comment: i'm sorry... i read it 3 times now and still don't know what you want to do

Comment: `(x.Name.LocalName != "Country") && (x.Name.LocalName != "OldName")` ?

Comment: Yep blacktempel perfect :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.Where( (x.Name.LocalName != "Country") && (x.Name.LocalName != "OldName") )
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, definitely, just add it like this:

```
 .Where(x => x.Name.LocalName != "Country" && x.Name.LocalName != "OldName")
```